# onLocationChanged never called , GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, google-api-client

I am trying to get continuous location updates by running a background service. While I debug the code **onConnected(Bundle b)** is called and location update request is called. But **onLocationChanged(Location location)**  is never called. Below is my code:

```
    public class LocationUpdateService extends Service implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {


    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    Location mCurrentLocation;

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        double lat = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
        double lng = mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();
    }

    //GoogleApiClient
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i("onConnected", "GoogleApiClient");

        Toast.makeText(this, "Location  service connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        createLocationRequest();
        startLocationUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    //Service
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        buildGoogleApiClient();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return START_STICKY; // run until explicitly stopped.
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void startLocationUpdate() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                googleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
    }

    void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }

    void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest().create()
                .setInterval(5000)
                .setFastestInterval(5000)
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }
}
```

I can't understand where I am making mistake, while I have followed [android docs](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdates). I am testing on real device and app has location permissions.

service in menifest:

```
<service
            android:name=".locations.LocationUpdateService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"></service>
```

Call of service in activity:

```
startService(new Intent(BaseActivity.this, LocationUpdateService.class));
```

Comment: First of all you've to mention this service in your manifest file and then you should bind this service to any of your activity or fragment

Comment: @Bhavnik I have already mentioned service in menifest and service also get started from activity. While debugging I get accross **OnConnected()** method. but never get call for **onLocationChanged**

Answer (score 0):

What is your android phone SDK and how are you asking for the permissions on the manifest file?
If your phone SDK is 23 or higher the way you ask for permissions is different.

Answer (score 0):

It was just a stupid debugging issue. I found my device location Access was off in advance settings.